# `row.dot(M).dot(row.T) for row in x` as native numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector and matrix compution which work great as follows:

```
import numpy as np

r = 1
c = 13
x = np.ones((r, c)) # rxc
M = np.ones((c, c)) # cxc square    
Z = x.dot(M).dot(x.T) # (rxr) = (rxc).(cxc).(cxr)
print Z.shape

def mul(a,b): return a*b
assert reduce(mul,Z.shape)==r  # Z should have one value for each row
```

I'd like to perform the same transform on the rows of x for an x that had many rows, like so:

```
r = 99
x = np.ones((r, c)) # rxc
... as above ...
```

This fails because Z (sensibly) ends up as a (99x99). But what I'd like is a (99x1) or (1x99), which can be calculated, as:

```
Z2 = np.array([row.dot(M).dot(row.T) for row in x])
```

Is there a way to calculate Z2 more directly in numpy, instead of using python iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This multiply trick can get the result that you want. Basically, we use multiply and sum as a dot product by row instead of using `dot`

```
(x.dot(M) * x).sum(axis=1)
```

I tested on 1000 x 10000 array to see that this trick works faster.

```
r = 1000
c = 10000
x = np.ones((r, c)) # rxc
M = np.ones((c, c)) # cxc square

%timeit (x.dot(M) * x).sum(axis=1) 
>> 1 loop, best of 3: 1.59 s per loop
%timeit np.array([row.dot(M).dot(row.T) for row in x])
>> 1 loop, best of 3: 41.9 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `Z2` is the simply the diagonal of `Z`, which you can get with `np.diagonal(Z)`:

```
import numpy as np
c = 13
r = 99
x = np.random.normal(size=(r, c)) # rxc
M = np.random.normal(size=(c, c)) # cxc square    
Z = x.dot(M).dot(x.T) # (rxr) = (rxc).(cxc).(cxr)
np.isclose(np.array([row.dot(M).dot(row.T) for row in x]),
           np.diagonal(Z)).all()
```

Or you can do it the cool way, all in one go with `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk,ki -> i',x,M,x.T)
```

Bear in mind that `np.einsum` <s>needs to parse the string</s> does some other things that make it less efficient than plain matrix multiplication, so if you're particularly concerned about performance, this method is slower.

On a side note, the product of 3 matrices is different from `Z2` because `Z2` doesn't compute entries like `(first row of x).(M).(second column of x.T)`, etc.; these are the non-diagonal entries of `Z`.

Comment: `np.einsum` should be faster than `np.diagonal` as it only calculates the relevant terms.  I think `np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', x, M, x)` might be a tiny bit faster still, as it doesn't require manipulating the pointers for `x.T`

Comment: I tried it with larger arrays, and `np.einsum` is actually much slower, and it's not because of the parsing. I don't exactly know why, but it's most likely because the operations aren't as simple and straightforward as in the usual matrix multiplication where NumPy uses a really efficient implementation. In fact, titipata's solution of just doing `(x.dot(M) * x).sum(axis=1)` is faster, and probably as fast as it gets.